# Getting the return type of a member parametric function in unevaluated contexts

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Given the following code (a reduced situation of a complexer code):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<unsigned i>
struct index_st
{
    using type = void;
};

struct pack
{
    template<unsigned index>
    static typename index_st<index>::type get();

    template<unsigned index>
    using unpack_t = decltype(get<index>());
};

template<typename P, unsigned index>
struct unpack
{
    using type = typename P::unpack_t<index>;
};

int main()
{
    unpack<pack, 3> u;
}
```

The following compilation error is thrown by gcc (4.8.1):

```
sample.cpp:21:38: error: expected ';' before '<' token
     using type = typename P::unpack_t<index>;
                                      ^
sample.cpp:21:38: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
sample.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct unpack<pack, 3u>':
sample.cpp:26:21:   required from here
sample.cpp:21:38: error: 'typename pack::unpack_t' names 'template<unsigned int index> using unpack_t = decltype (get<index>())', which is not a type
```

My objetive is getting the type returned by `pack::get<index>()` inside the `unpack` structure.

I've tried to do it with and without the `using` statement, using `std::result_of` and other combinations, but in all cases, I was not capable to get the return type of `get` (a parametric member function).

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Add `template` keyword: `using type = typename P::template unpack_t<index>;`.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp 30 more upvotes to be able to insta-dup close!

Comment: @Yakk it's actually only 3 more answers in [tag:c++] that is required, the vote count is slow on updating; I'm working on it!

Answer (score 2):

```
 using type = typename P::unpack_t<index>;
```

Here `P` is a [dependent type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) (since it's a template parameter), this means that the compiler must explicitly be told to treat `unpack_t` as a template.

```
 using type = typename P::template unpack_t<index>;
```

---

Further information:

- [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/1090079)